# Return Category and Subcategory Data in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please check this controller bellow carefully. Here i have two table Level1Cats and Level2Cats And i need to return ViewBag data to display Main category and its under child category. Problem is i can return both table in different Variable that's why i cant do foreach loop for display Category and its related sub category. View also part also included please check bellow. Please give me idea to return data in single variable as List or somehow so i can do a easy foreach to display category and sub category properly.
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var ctx = new db_zikanalyticsEntities())
            {
                var L1Cats = ctx.Level1Cats.ToArray();
                var L2Cats = ctx.Level2Cats.ToArray();



                foreach (var L1Cat in L1Cats)
                {
                    var foo = L2Cats.Where(x => x.Level1CatId == L1Cat.Level1CatId).ToList();
                    //if ()
                    //{

                    //}
                }

                //ViewBag.MainCategory = L1Cats;
                ViewBag.L1Cats = L1Cats;
                return View();
            }


        }
```

[image: Level1Cats table picture]
[image: Level1Cats table picture]
Above first picture is Level1Cats table and second picture is Level2Cats table

View:

```
@foreach (var v in ViewBag.L1Cats)
         {
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="mainCategory">
                    <h4><u><b>@v.Name</b></u></h4>
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </h4>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Need to return sub category name here</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a ViewModel, exposing the tables as properties and referencing the model in the View? then you can not only do whatever you want but also have type safety

Comment: If you have correctly set up your navigation properties, then its simply `var model = ctx.Level1Cats.Include(x => x.Level2Cats); return View(model);` and then just use nested loops in your view.

Comment: This method not works. https://ibb.co/fSZVdw @StephenMuecke

Comment: I don't know what your model properties are (you have not bothered to show any relevant information). Just change `Level2Cats` to what ever your property name for the collection property is

Comment: And I assume you have included `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Can you tell me how to use return View(model); from my View? @StephenMuecke

Comment: `return View(model);` goes in the controller, not the view. And in the view its `@model IEunmerable<Level1Cats>` and `foreach (var level1 in Model) { @level1.Name foreach( var level2 in level1.Level2Cats) { @level2.Name } }`

Comment: sorry to bother you but i am having error in view to use "@ model" plz check https://ibb.co/gqvsrG @StephenMuecke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155741/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-john-lk).

Comment: Hi , I think you are missing to add a list property in your main model like a  listsubcat List<catsub> {get;} {set;} , another thing could be, you are missing to add primary key for category and foreign key in your subcatergory, basically Entity Framework use you map table to lazy load the nested information, have a look in one example I created to explain how to map the class [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oAufdL)

Comment: Here it is another example using Asp Mvc Fiddle [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mDuPyX)